# Sending a get request with Spring RestTemplate that returns an array

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, nominatim

I want to get 50 random addresses from Nominatim at once for data generation purposes. I have it working without using Spring Framework, but I need to implement it using Spring RestTemplate.

Getting 50 per second is pretty important because Nominatim is fairly slow and I want to be able to generate large sets of data.

This works to give me 50 responses at once:

```
public void processRequest() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        do {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(getURI());
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            try {
                this.responseAsString = responseToJsonString(response);
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } while (this.responseAsString.equals(INVALID_LAT_LONG_RESPONSE));
```

I tried following [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-list) but it would not work.

Making the ResponseEntity of String type only returns the first value of the 50 I am expecting.

```
{"place_id":78213552,"licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright","osm_type":"way","osm_id":10055484,"lat":"32.920202","lon":"-97.528753","display_name":"Charles Avenue, Azle, Tarrant County, Texas, 76020, USA","class":"highway","type":"residential","importance":0.1,"address":{"road":"Charles Avenue","town":"Azle","county":"Tarrant County","state":"Texas","postcode":"76020","country":"USA","country_code":"us"}}
```

Making it a String[] gives me a 406 not acceptable error.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplate.exchange(
                uri,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                null,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {}
                );
```

I get the same 406 error when I try using an Address POJO and when I try using an Address[] for the type.

Here are the fields from the Address POJO. Each field has a getter and a setter (names are just the default ones Eclipse gives, so it shouldn't cause an issue with Jackson's parsing).

```
package com.bottomline.ml.generator.nominatimRequest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Address {

    @JsonProperty("place_id")
    private long placeId;

    @JsonProperty("licence")
    private String licence;

    @JsonProperty("osm_type")
    private String osmType;

    @JsonProperty("osm_id")
    private String osmId;

    @JsonProperty("lon")
    private double longitude;

    @JsonProperty("lat")
    private double latitude;

    @JsonProperty("display_name")
    private String displayName;

    @JsonProperty("class")
    private String elementClass;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String elementType;

    @JsonProperty("importance")
    private double importance;

    @JsonProperty("address")
    private String addressDetails;
```

Comment: can you show the response string output?

Comment: show us the response body. You have a method `responseToJson` so I assume that you have a json response. You just need to create a POJO that matches the json format

Comment: @Deadpool I edited the post to clarify

Comment: show the `Address` pojo @EthanSeal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The following works:

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = getParams();
ResponseEntity<String> response = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(SEARCH, String.class, params);
```

where getParams() is:

```
    private static HashMap<String, Object> getParams() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        String ids = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_REQUESTS; i++) {
            ids += "W" + Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(10000000) + 10000000) + ',';
        }

        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("osmId", ids);
        params.put("format", "json");

        return params;
    }
```

and I have the following fields:

```
    private static String osmId = "&osm_ids={osmId}";
    private static String format = "&format={format}";
    private static String SEARCH = <your favorite nominatim server> + osmId + format;
```

There was most likely an issue with converting the URI to a String such that the commas in the parameters were being read as %2C, not as a comma. The HashMap params fixes that probably.